# Extract specific observations of csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I've imported a csv file using read.csv.
It gives me a data frame with 18k observations of 1 variable, which looks like this:

```
    V1
1   Energies (kJ/mol)
2              Bond          Angle    Proper Dih.  Improper Dih.          LJ-14
3       3.12912e+04    4.12307e+03    1.63677e+04    1.25619e+02    1.04394e+04
4        Coulomb-14        LJ (SR)   Coulomb (SR)      Potential Pressure (bar)
5       9.21339e+04    2.82339e+05   -1.15807e+06   -7.21252e+05   -7.25781e+03
6              Step           Time         Lambda
7                 1        1.00000        0.00000
8      Energies (kJ/mol)
9              Bond          Angle    Proper Dih.  Improper Dih.          LJ-14
10      2.71553e+04    4.11858e+03    1.63855e+04    1.22226e+02    1.03903e+04
11       Coulomb-14        LJ (SR)   Coulomb (SR)      Potential Pressure (bar)
12      9.20926e+04    2.65253e+05   -1.15928e+06   -7.43766e+05   -7.27887e+03
13             Step           Time         Lambda
14                2        2.00000        0.00000

...
```

I want to extract the Potential energy in a vector. I've tried grep and readLines in multiple varieties and functions, but nothing works. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks! :)

Comment: It looks as though the file that you passed the `read.csv()` command was not actually a csv file.  It instead looks like a specially formatted output file.  I would double check that the input file is indeed a comma separated values (csv) file.  If it is not, then you may need to convert it.  Please check the Wikipedia article on [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files for more information.

Comment: thanks! I sensed something like that, but wasnt sure. Unfortunately I just have access to my backup file. I'll try to convert it, hope it works then! edit: it actually is a csv file.....now I'm depressed :D

Comment: So, with that data there would only be two lines that had any interest to you, the one immediately below the lines with "Potential"?

Comment: It may be helpful if you post first few lines of csv file.

Comment: I agree...  Please post the first few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is this the right answer (from a former fizzsics major):

```
Lines <- readLines(textConnection("1   Energies (kJ/mol)
2              Bond          Angle    Proper Dih.  Improper Dih.          LJ-14
3       3.12912e+04    4.12307e+03    1.63677e+04    1.25619e+02    1.04394e+04
4        Coulomb-14        LJ (SR)   Coulomb (SR)      Potential Pressure (bar)
5       9.21339e+04    2.82339e+05   -1.15807e+06   -7.21252e+05   -7.25781e+03
6              Step           Time         Lambda
7                 1        1.00000        0.00000
8      Energies (kJ/mol)
9              Bond          Angle    Proper Dih.  Improper Dih.          LJ-14
10      2.71553e+04    4.11858e+03    1.63855e+04    1.22226e+02    1.03903e+04
11       Coulomb-14        LJ (SR)   Coulomb (SR)      Potential Pressure (bar)
12      9.20926e+04    2.65253e+05   -1.15928e+06   -7.43766e+05   -7.27887e+03
13             Step           Time         Lambda
14                2        2.00000        0.00000"))

> grep("Potential", Lines)   # identify the lines with "Potential"
[1]  4 11
```

Need to move to the next line and get the 5th item:

```
> read.table(text=Lines[ grep("Potential", Lines)+1])[ , 5]
[1] -721252 -743766
```